# What's the meaning of this extra rest?

Tags: notation, time-signatures, ornaments, staccato

This is the first bar of [**F. W. Mecham Op 92** - American Patrol](https://imslp.org/wiki/American_Patrol,_Op.92_(Meacham,_Frank_W.))

[image: American patrol first bar]

```
Semiquaver triplet + quaver + quaver rest + quarter rest
1/8                + 1/8    + 1/8            + 1/4             = 2/4 + 1/8
```

What's with the meaning of the extra eighth?

Comment: There is no extra silence.

Comment: I also think this question has been answered elsewhere before. But I have another question: are the grace notes always printed with a slure? and does this slur say something for the interpretation? and how can you play this accent on the first eighth note in  pppp????

Comment: 8th note + 8th rest + quarter rest = 2 beats in 2/4 meter. There aren't any extra values.

Comment: The key to seeing this is the smaller note heads on the grace notes. Hard to miss at first glance but once you realize there would be too many notes if they weren't grace notes it should jump out at you. Moving forward you will see it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The small triplets are grace notes. They exist outside the normal metre of the measure. The D eighth-notes are on the first beat, or downbeat.

Comment: I thought they were *eighth-notes,* but I'm English and call them quavers.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thanks for the catch - I'm from the UK too but most people on this site seem to use the fractional names so I've been following suit. Unsuccessfully in this case!